# "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP" error?

Tags: tls

[image: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP]

I'm getting this error message each time I try to open wikipedia.org from my laptop since a week now. First I thought it was due to VPN connection, but even when it's closed I also get this message.

Few hours ago I opened it using my phone -in the same LAN with my laptop- and it worked, but still not working and getting the same message from different browsers.

Am I hacked? and what can I do to solve this problem?!!

**EDIT:** I'm using windows 10, and my phone is android 6m and both chrome and firefox are up-to-date. Another issue is I just tried to open it from a linux VM I'm using, and i got the same message too !! :(

Comment: Which OS are you on? Which versions of which browsers are you using?

Comment: For me, `www.wikipedia.org` and my browser agree to use the cipher suite `(ECDHE_ECDSA with X25519), and (CHACHA20_POLY1305).` Both of which are fairly new. My guess is that you're using an older browser / OS that doesn't know about the new crypto.

Comment: Can you use Nmap on any of those systems? `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers www.wikipedia.org -p443` ought to show all the ciphers that are being allowed. We can compare to what others are seeing to know if something is interfering with you specifically.